# how to find most similar patches from a set patches using matlab?

Tags: matlab

initially an image is divided into 5*5 blocks with 3 overlapping pixel and each block is stored in an array(A1).
Then done bicubic interpolation for the same image and again divide the image into 5*5 blocks with 3 overlapping pixel and stored in another array(A2).
Then i need to find most similar blocks from A2 to A1.ie, for every block in A2 find most similar 3 blocks in  A1.

How to find this using matlab?

Comment: please let us know what you have tried??

Comment: Are you, by any chance, trying to implement ["single image super resolution"](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~vision/SingleImageSR.html "Glasner Bagon and Irani ICCV 2009") ?

Comment: what version of matlab and what tool boxes do you have?

Comment: You may what to look into [`knnsearch`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/knnsearch.html). Alternatively, you may find [this approximate NN (ANN) class](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~bagon/matlab.html#ann) useful.

Comment: am already using "knnsearch".Using Knnsearch,it take each 5*5 matrix from A2 and another 5*5 matrix from A1 and compare each row and return the index in a 5*3 matrix.if A1 contain 10 5*5 matrix and A2 contain 10 5*5 matrix then knnsearch return 100(10*10) 5*3 matrix.But i need, each matrix in A2 have 3 most similar 5*5 matrix in A1.Is it possible?

Comment: @Shai yes, am doing a project based on the paper 'single image super resolution with multiscale similarity learnig'.

Comment: @Shai am using matlab R2012a

Comment: @user3148302 1. One thing I learned about this type of super resolution is that it is SUPER CRITICAL to have the center of the low-res patch EXACTLY aligned with the center of the high-res patch. Just down sampling and hoping the centers will co-incide will yield sub-optimal results. 2. If you are looking for massive comparison of image patches you might want to look at [Patch-Match](http://gfx.cs.princeton.edu/pubs/Barnes_2009_PAR/index.php) and [its extension](http://gfx.cs.princeton.edu/pubs/Barnes_2010_TGP/index.php)

Comment: @Shai is their any default function for matlab for patchmatch????can u  suggest such a function???

Comment: @user3148302 AFAIK PatchMatch has a matlab interface - look at thier distribution code. You are looking at quite a large project - take your time setting up your tools.

Comment: @Shai need to finish my project during january last week...is it possible for me to complete it???

Comment: @user3148302 a wise man once told me: "todo es possible - nada seguro". work hard. depending on your expected results (beating state-of-the-art vs. recovering reported results) ...

Comment: @Shai i will do my best....

Comment: @Shai can u suggest how to do random correspondence algorithm in matlab?????

Comment: is it possible to use 'nearestneighbor' in matlab????

Comment: @user3148302 download the code from the extended version of patchmatch. It has a working matlab interface - all you need is to read the instruction and compile the c++ files in the package.

Comment: Are you still looking for help with this?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly:

1. Vectorize each patch
2. Construct full weighted adjacency matrix 50x50 (there is a lot of [code](http://www.cad.zju.edu.cn/home/dengcai/Data/code/constructW.m) out there in matlab)
3. For each row or col which refers to a patch either in A1 or A2, let say in A1, take the 3 biggest values in in this row or col excluding the ones that belong in the same image, i.e. A1.

Good luck ;D